# BeautifulSoup scraper downloaded images are corrupt

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I greatly need help for my code. I was attempting to do an exercise from a book and I followed it exactly. The code worked and it downloaded the images. However, all the images that was downloaded were corrupted. I have no idea whats causing it or what I missed.

Thanks.

```
#! python3
# downloadXkcd.py - Downloads every single XKCD comic.
import requests, os, bs4

url = 'http://xkcd.com'
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)

while not url.endswith('#'):
    # Download the page.
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

    # Find the URL of the comic image.
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Could not find comic image')
    else:
        comicUrl = comicElem[0].get('src')
        # Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s' %(comicUrl))
        res.raise_for_status()

    # Save the image to ./xkcd.
    imagefile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        imagefile.write(chunk)
    imagefile.close()

    # Get the prev button's url
    prevlink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
    url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevlink.get('href')

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing wrong data to the file:

> for chunk in **res**.iter_content(100000)

**res** is the data of the webpage. You should be getting the data of the image with the url **comicUrl** instead. I think you forgot this line:

```py
print('Downloading image %s' %(comicUrl))
res = requests.get('http:' + comicUrl)
```

Note: I added *http:* before the url because the image urls you are extracting lack this. You should define a function to check whether it is necessary to add this schema.

Comment: Oh wow thanks alot! I cant believe I missed a line. This code was really making me go crazy. 
Appreciate your help.